# does ssh use sni headers and how SNI inject to ssh tunnel connection

Tags: ssh, http-headers, ssh-tunnel, sni

There are lot of tools change the sni in data packet. Does ssh use sni or how HTTP injector likes software change the SNI and browse the around the internet.

Comment: I too want to know about this. How does those programs actually change the SNI, can ssh do it natively, and so on. I will start a bounty on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SNI is an extension to the TLS protocol which allows a client to specify a virtual domain during the connection handshake, as [part of the `ClientHello` message](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6066#section-3).

SSH and TLS are different protocols and SSH does not use SNI. Changing the SNI while making an HTTPS request just requires changing the value the TLS client presents to the target server while connecting, which is, by default, the name of the host used to resolve the IP address of the TLS server; this can be done by openssl, for example, or even by manually adding an entry to your */etc/hosts*, pointing a fabricated host name to a TLS server IP address and using the former to connect to the latter. In these cases, TLS clients complain about the name mismatch between the server certificate and the host name (SNI) you are using - but that can usually be turned off.

Here is how to use a fake SNI *example.com* while connecting to *[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)* using the openssl's `-servername` argument:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -servername example.com
```

And here is how to perform a full HTTPS request using cURL, passing the `--insecure` option to stop it complaining about the certificate name mismatch as well as manually specifying the `Host` header (which cURL would otherwise take from the passed URL), with the `--connect-to` argument used to *resolve* our *host:port* fabricated pair to the real one:

```sh
curl --connect-to example.com:443:www.google.com:443 --insecure \
     -H "Host: www.google.com" https://example.com/
```